# Setting up dual monitors with integrated graphics

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Trying to set up dual monitors but the monitors are mirrored and will not change. They also say laptop but I am using a desktop. I have 2 viewsonic monitors at 1080p. I'm using a sandy bridge cpu with intergrated graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the System->Preferences->Monitors applet?  Or from a command line;

```
$ gnome-display-properties
```

That applet has a button "Detect monitors" and a checkbox for "Same image in all monitors".

Also, you have the laptop lid closed while connected to the two monitors?